# MVC 3 Custom Templates and EditorForModel confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

So as I understand it

Given a view model

```
public class MyViewModel{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public MyClass Class {get; set;}
}
```

.. a View Views\MyController\MyAction.cshtml

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

.. a partial View Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateTime.chstml

```
@model DateTime
Some Date
```

.. another partial View Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\MyClass.cshtml

```
@model MyClass
My Class
```

.. I should get

```
Date
Some Date
Class
My Class
```

.. But I just get

```
Date
Some Date
```

So it seems DisplayForModel finds DateTime template but not my custom template, even though I am following the conventions of naming it by the type of the property.

Am I missing something. I am using MVC 3 and believe this feature was already available in MVC 2

Comment: That is strange--your syntax look ok, but the only way I could make it work was an explicit call to `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Class)`

Comment: Yes that is what I found too, but all the tutorials I have seen seem to indicate that this is supported

Comment: No MyClass is not a List. A list would be declared as List<MyClass>. When the Framework would come to render a list, I believe it will use the Collection Template.

Comment: you should post your update as an answer to the question (I'd give it another upvote)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having perused the MVC source code, it turns out that this is, in fact, not possible.

The reason is that `@Html.DisplayForModel()` attempts to find a template to use for rendering, by:

- first looking for the name of the model's type, i.e. `MyViewModel.cshtml` or `MyViewModel.vbhtml` or `MyViewModel.ascx` etc, in location `~\Views`, `~\Views[ControllerName]`, `~\Views\DisplayTemplates`, `~\Views\Shared`, `~\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates`
- if it is not found it will walk down the model's base types, attempting each type's name in turn
- if none are found, it will eventually end up at `Object`, for which there exists a built-in template

The object template is designed such that it retrieves all the model's properties, for rendering, from metadata based on the following condition:

```
metadata.ShowForDisplay
&& metadata.ModelType != typeof(EntityState)
&& !metadata.IsComplexType 
&& !templateInfo.Visited(metadata)
```

Therefore any property that is a complex type will always be excluded. I think the confusion arises from [Brad Wilson's post on custom object template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html), where he creates a custom object template and addresses the issue of Shallow Dive vs Deep Dive. By implementing a custom deep dive object template this will override the built-in object template and complex types can be rendered.

Comment: Yes, by default MVC will only do a shallow dive (ie only 1 level of walking the object hiearchy), and will only call the `ToString()` on your complex type.  You can use a template similar to Brads in the post you mention to override `Object` and do a deep dive if you so desire.